# Use In App purchase or Third Party Payment gateway

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

We have query regarding to Use In-App Purchase or Third Party Payment Gateway for Below Functionality in our application.  So, please review case and give your suggestions which way of payment we should use such that our Application will be not rejected regarding this functionality.

Application provides the Service to offer as well as book a Parking Space in Argentina.

1. Where user can offer his Empty Parking Space to other User with fixed Charges. User need to pay some tokens (digital currency) to use parking Space and Other end User will receive the Tokens for His/her Parking Space.
2. User Need to Buy Tokens from App by paying Money as per different Plans (Eg: 15 token for $100). User can use this Tokens for taking service of Parking Space from Other User.
3. So, the parking service is not within the application. User can only buy Parking Space from App using Tokens which he/she bought from Application by paying money.

Shall we use In-App Purchase for buying Tokens in Application or shall we Use Third Party Payment Gateway as the Service is provided out of Application?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

As you are not paying for the parking space but paying for a virtual currency then that would be fine to use in app purchase (it will be a consumable item).

You may find these guides useful:

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase

and:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH1-SW1